# How to resize image in node js before writeFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var file_path = files.file.path;
fs.readFile(file_path, function (err, data) {
  fs.writeFile(file_path, data, function (err) {
    res.end(JSON.stringify({
      message: 'file uploaded successfully',
      success: true
    });
  });
});
```

I tried **resizeImg** library

```
var file_path = files.file.path;
fs.readFile(file_path, function (err, data) {
  let buf = resizeImg(data, {
        width: 250, height: 250
  });

  fs.writeFile(file_path, buf, function (err) {
    res.end(JSON.stringify({
      message: 'file uploaded successfully',
      success: true
    })
  })
})
```

but that didn't work. It creates a file that won't open. I think this library uses an already existing image to resize.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you link the library you're using from npm? :)

Comment: does the library resizes the gif file or animated webp file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't open because you are not writing the actual file buffer but `Promise<buffer>`. The `resizeImg` returns a promise so you need to either await it or use then to get the response. Something like this should work

```
var file_path = files.file.path;
fs.readFile(file_path, async function(err, data) {
  const buf = await resizeImg(data, {
    width: 250,
    height: 250
  });
  fs.writeFile(file_path, buf, function(err) {
    res.end(
      JSON.stringify({
        message: "file uploaded successfully",
        success: true
      })
    );
  });
});
```